# how can i query utxo to bitcoind(using bitcoin-cli) with public-private key not wallet

Tags: utxo, listunspent

i want make a transaction to send bitcoin to others.

so i need utxo by someones' adfress.

but bitcoin-cli listunspent command only allows address in wallet.

is it any idea to query listunspent with address not in wallet?
using public, private key.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the uxto of the other address to be able to send it BTC. You just need the address.

If you want to list unspents of an address you don't have the keys for, I don't think bitcoind can help you. However, you can use explorers like blockchain.info: https://blockchain.info/unspent?active=35QEobWVUKjMY2HwKATYYQXRGzXJvdXQCy&format=html (there's also JSON if you want it).

Comment: thanks for reply :).  Yes, I already know about that site.
I am making wallets using some libraries.
I want to know total balance of addresses, 
and  some libraries(bitcore-lib) needs to utxos values for making transactions. 
so that's why i need that.

Comment: so if u wanna query utxo from address( not wallet ) using bitcoin library ( bitcore or something include bitcoin-cli ), do u have any ideas for that?

Comment: Not out of my head, you could look at https://github.com/eklitzke/utxodump